# How to avoid anemic domain and avoid putting your data access class inside your domain class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm trying to move my business logic out of my service class and my controller, and put it inside my business class.

```
public interface IFoo{
  IBar CreateBar(creationParameters);
}
public class FirstFoo : IFoo{
  IBar CreateBar(creationParameters){
    return new FirstBar(creationParameter.Id);
  }
}
public interface IBar{
  void DoSomething();
}
public class FirstBar : IBar{
  FirstBar(int id){...}
  void DoSomething(){
    //well... do something
  }
}
public class SecondBar : IBar{
  FirstBar(int id){...}
  void DoSomething(){
    //well... do something else
  }
}
```

Let's imagine I need to create a SecondFoo that'll need access to the database to know of it must create a FirstBar or a SecondBar, how do I do that ? I inject my data source inside the SecondFoo's constructor ? Service locator ? I move the createBar out of the IFoo ?

EDIT: I'm not looking for a definition of the Factory Pattern, the createBar method might be something like "changeBar" or "doBusinessWithBar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's imagine I need to create a SecondFoo that'll need access to the database to know of it must create a FirstBar or a SecondBar

It seems `SecondFoo` needs some kind of *decision logic* to decide whether to create a `FirstBar` or a `SecondBar`. That logic could be factored out in a *strategy* interface, of which the database access  implementation would be used in production. You could inject the strategy via the constructor.

```
IBar CreateBar(creationParameters) {
  if (strategy.ShouldCreateFirst(creationParameters)) {
    return new FirstBar(creationParameter.Id);     
  }  
  else {
    return new SecondBar(creationParameter.Id);     
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems fine, but if we abuse of this pattern we will end up with an anemyc domain model right ?

Comment: Well, not necessarily. Ideally, the strategy is part of the domain, like the `TaxEligibilityCheck` in [this example](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2012/03/some-oo-design.html).